# Ignored names still show in tree view in ATOM

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I have checked 'Exclude VCS Ignored paths' in Core settings. And
'Hide ignored names', 'Hide VCS ignored files' from tree-view package settings.
And then closed and reopened the ATOM. But still .gitignore files are visible.
Can anyone help me to find what I'm doing wrong?

My .gitignore file contains the following

```
.editorconfig
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but a possible workaround would be adding

```
.editorconfig, node_modules
```

to the Ignored Names section (`Settings > Core`) will hide these files and folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure that Ignored Names are added inside `Settings > Core`, you have to select "Hide Ignored Names" in Settings > Packages > tree view:

[image]